# How does map assign the new value in the following case?

Tags: javascript

I have an array called `this.list`. I wanted to map through it's items and give a new value to those items:

```
this.list = this.list.map(item => {
  if (item.id === target.id) {
    item.dataX = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x'))
    item.dataY = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y'))
  }
  return item
})
```

But to my surprise, this also worked:

```
this.list.map(item => {
  if (item.id === target.id) {
    item.dataX = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x'))
    item.dataY = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y'))
  }
  return item
})
```

How come map is assigning a new value to `this.json` if I'm not using any assignment at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your example, comments inline:

```
// The function map returns a _new_ array
// containing all of the existing elements.
// Then is assigned to the existing variable
// overwriting the original array.
this.list = this.list.map(item => {

  // Here "item" refers to the actual object element in the
  // existing list any assignments to this object will affect
  // the existing item in the list.
  if (item.id === target.id) {

    // Here are your assigments.
    item.dataX = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x'));
    item.dataY = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y'));
  }

  // Although the item is returned and would replace the
  // existing element in the new resulting list, the item
  // returned is in fact the actual element that is _already_
  // currently in the list.
  return item;
});
```

Therefore in this case the following is equivalent in terms of result based upon the fact you are assigning to the original variable and updating in place the original values:

```
this.list.forEach(item => {
  if (item.id === target.id) {
    item.dataX = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x'));
    item.dataY = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y'));
  }
});
```

To perform this in a way that doesn't mutate the original objects, if that is what you desire:

```
var result = this.list.map(item => {
  return target.id === item.id ? {
    id: item.id,
    dataX: parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')),
    dataY: parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y'))
  } : item;
});
```

Or if `item` has additional data that you need to carry across you may need to somehow copy the object: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object). One alternative is to model the types around this, for example:

```
class Item {
  constructor(id, x, y) {
    this.id = id;
    this.dataX = dataX;
    this.dataY = dataY;
  }

  // Immutability style setter, returns the result
  // as a new instance.
  withData(dataX, dataY) {
    return new Item(this.id, dataX, dataY);
  }
}

var result = this.list.map(item => {
  return item.id === target.id ? item.withData(
    parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')),
    parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y'))
  ) : item;
});
```

In the above example `this.list` is the untouched original array containing all of the elements as they were prior to the map operation.

`result` contains a mix of "updated" elements (new instances of the elements that  that matched `target.id` and *original* items that didn't.

#### Follow the instances...

If we were to number all of the instances, before the map operation in the first example using `map` and assigning back to `this.list` we might have:

```
this.list
  Array 1
  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3
  - Item 4
```

After the map operation, the items are the same instances, and have been updated, but the array is a different instance:

```
this.list -> map -> this.list
  Array 1             Array 2 (NEW)
  - Item 1       ->   - Item 1
  - Item 2       ->   - Item 2
  - Item 3       ->   - Item 3
  - Item 4       ->   - Item 4
```

In the `forEach` example, both before the `forEach` operation and after the result is the same, the instances have been updated in place:

```
this.list (forEach) this.list (No change)
  Array 1             Array 1
  - Item 1            - Item 1
  - Item 2            - Item 2
  - Item 3            - Item 3
  - Item 4            - Item 4
```

In each of the immutable examples `this.list` is the same as before but `result` will be a different array instance and the matched items will be different instances, in the following example `Item 1` was matched and updated:

```
this.list -> map -> result             this.list (Untouched)
  Array 1             Array 2 (NEW)      Array 1
  - Item 1            - Item 5 (NEW)     - Item 1
  - Item 2       ->   - Item 2           - Item 2
  - Item 3       ->   - Item 3           - Item 3
  - Item 4       ->   - Item 4           - Item 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Refering to the `map` function docs:

> map does not mutate the array on which it is called (although callback, if invoked, may do so).

Note that the `item` object you're using in the `callback` is a reference to the actual `this.list` element and in your case you're mutating the `item` object.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript stores objects as references so when you map over an array, you are changing the original object. You can see the same behaviour in the code bellow:

```
let original = [{x: 5}];
let copied = original;
copied[0].x = 6;
console.log(original[0].x); // 6
```

You would have to re-create the object or clone it somehow.

```
  this.list = this.list.map(item => {
    if (item.id === target.id) {
      item = {
        id: target.id,
        dataX: parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')),
        dataY: parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')),
        ...
      };
    }
    return item
  })
```